# Munin Windows Sum Stack graph

Tags: windows, munin

I am trying to stack multiple graph in one with munin. The idea is to stack all the web servers CPU graph into one graph.

Munin configuration source graph:

```
[WEB1.virtualservers]
    address 10.11.6.72
    use_node_name yes
    memory.swap.label swap
    memory.swap.draw STACK
    memory.swap.info Swap memory used

[WEB2.virtualservers]
    address 10.11.6.73
    use_node_name yes
    memory.swap.label swap
    memory.swap.draw STACK
    memory.swap.info Swap memory used

[WEB3.virtualservers]
    address 10.11.6.74
    use_node_name yes
    memory.swap.label swap
    memory.swap.draw STACK
    memory.swap.info Swap memory used
```

Here is the munin configuration I applied for the sum/stack:

```
[virtualservers;secure2]
update no
contacts no
web_cpu.graph_title Secure - CPU Usage
web_cpu.cpu_user.label user
web_cpu.cpu_user.sum WEB1.virtualservers:cpu_user.user WEB2.virtualservers:cpu_user.user WEB3.virtualservers:cpu_user.user
```

I tried:

- Update yes
- Update no
- sum
- stack
- cpu_user.user
- cpu_user.cpu
- cpu.cpu_user
- user.cpu
- cpu.cpu

Here is the error I get every time:

```
2015/02/03 10:10:35 [ERROR] filename is empty for $VAR1 = {
  '#%#name' => 'z1_0',
  'cdef' => 'z1_0,UN,0,z1_0,IF',
  'graph' => 'no',
  'label' => 'z1_0'
};
, WEB1.virtualservers:cpu_user.user
2015/02/03 10:10:35 [PERL WARNING] Use of uninitialized value within @group in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Munin/Master/Utils.pm line 1171, <GEN1> line 745.
2015/02/03 10:10:35 [ERROR] filename is empty for $VAR1 = {
  '#%#name' => 'z1_1',
  'cdef' => 'z1_1,UN,0,z1_1,IF',
  'graph' => 'no',
  'label' => 'z1_1'
};
, WEB2.virtualservers:cpu_user.user
2015/02/03 10:10:35 [PERL WARNING] Use of uninitialized value within @group in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Munin/Master/Utils.pm line 1171, <GEN1> line 745.
2015/02/03 10:10:35 [ERROR] filename is empty for $VAR1 = {
  '#%#name' => 'z1_2',
  'cdef' => 'z1_2,UN,0,z1_2,IF,z1_0,ADDNAN,z1_1,ADDNAN',
  'colour' => undef,
  'draw' => undef,
  'graph' => 'yes',
  'label' => 'user'
};
, WEB3.virtualservers:cpu_user.user
```

**My source graph are working fine**

My web servers are running windows with munin-node-win32-1.6.0.0-installer... Not sure if this would cause this problem...

Answer (score 0):

Is it working with one external data source? goot. you have wrong with line:

```
web_cpu.cpu_user.sum WEB1.virtualservers:cpu_user.user WEB2.virtualservers:cpu_user.user WEB3.virtualservers:cpu_user.user
```

server doesn't know how to join data, because '.sum' isn't arithmetic operation.

in draw configuration you must do:

```
graph_order <list all direct order plus> DrawLocalName=ExternalDrawName.SpecifiedDrawName <next_def> <next2_def_etc> ...
```

Then later:

```
your_sum.cdef SpecifiedName1,SpecifiedName2,+,SpecifiedName3,+
```

note, cdef uses reverse polish notation. it is working like stack.